# xmlhttp.send() and PHP $_POST[]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make my first ajax form but I can't make it work. It is supposed to send some values to a .php file using POST method, make some calculations and retrieve the results. For some reason, I can't find the way to get the values in the php code. When I use print_r ($_POST) I can see all the values inserted in the form but if I try to get them using $_POST['input_name'] an  "Undefined index" error message is shown :S I don't know what I am doing wrong so any help would be appreciated.
Here is the code I'm using:

JQuery/Ajax:

```
$().ready(function() {
            $("#formulario").validate();
});

 function calcularR(){
            if ($('#formulario').valid() ) 
              {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("calculo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","calcularT.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var form = document.getElementById('formulario');
            var formData = new FormData(form);
            xmlhttp.send(formData);
            }
        }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="post" action="enviarR.php" enctype="application_x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div id="bulto1" class= "bult1">    
         <label class="form-label-top" id="label_alto" >Alto (cm)</label>
        <input type="text" class="required" id="alto1" name="alto1" size="21" maxlength="6" value = "" />

        <label class="form-label-top" id="label_largo" for="input_26">Largo (cm)</label>
        <input type="text" class="required" id="largo1" name="largo1" size="21" maxlength="6" value = "" />

        <label class="form-label-top" id="label_ancho" for="input_27">Ancho (cm)</label>
        <input type="text" class="required" id="ancho1" name="ancho1" size="21" maxlength="6" value = "" />

    </div>
   <input type="button" name="calcular" id="calcular" value="Calcular" onclick="calcularR()">
   <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Entrar">                           
</form>     
<div id="calculo" name="calculo"><b> </b></div>
```

PHP (calcularT.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['largo1']) && !empty($_POST['largo1'])){
    $largo = $_POST['largo1'];
    if(isset($_POST['ancho1']) && !empty($_POST['ancho1'])){
        $ancho = $_POST['ancho1'];
        if(isset($_POST['alto1']) && !empty($_POST['alto1'])){
            $alto = $_POST['alto1'];
            $t = calcularP($largo, $ancho, $alto);
            echo "Resultado: ".$t."<br/>";
         }else{
           echo "alto required <br/>";
         }
    }else{
      echo "ancho required<br/>";
    }
}else{
    echo "largo required<br/>";
}
```

This is just part of the code. First I try sending form data using

```
var alto = document.getElementById("alto").value;
var ancho = document.getElementById("ancho").value;
xmlhttp.send("alto="+alto+"&ancho="+ancho);
```

instead of

```
var formData = new FormData(form);
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

and it worked just fine but the form has more inputs and some of them are not always sent, so I thought it was better to use formData instead but, as I said, I can't find the way to get the values in the php code. 
Thanks in advance and please forgive my basic/bad english (this is not my native language. I'm learning that too :P)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST[$largo1]) && !empty($_POST[$largo1])){
```

is $largo1 being defined anywhere above that line? Maybe it is supposed to be $_POST['largo1']). Same for others

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Yes. I made a mistake editing the code to show. $largo1 and the others are defined above. For this example I should had used just $_POST['largo1'], $_POST['ancho1'] and $_POST['alto1']

Answer (score 0):

To get POST data in PHP you need to access a key of `$_POST` with a name that matches the name of the form control (or equivalent when you are building the form data manually with JS).

For example `$_POST['foo']`.

You are using a variable — `$_POST[$foo]` — which would work (albeit in an overcomplicated way) if `$foo = 'foo'`, but there is no sign that you have set `$foo` at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake editing the code to show. $largo1 and the other variables were set above but I didn't show it.For this example I should had written just $_POST['largo1'], $_POST['ancho1'] and $_POST['alto1'] :S

Answer (score 0):

First, trying to answer your question:

You say `print_r($_POST)` properly outputs the data submitted in the form, so the problem must lie in how you access those variables: to access form field 'largo1' you use `$_POST['largo1']` and so on. If `$largo1 = 'largo1'` then it's fine to use `$_POST[$largo1]`. See the difference.

Also, as you're using jQuery, take a look at jQuery's `.get` and `.serialize` methods as they can replace your ajax call as well as gathering the data from the form.

http://docs.jquery.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake editing the code to show. For this example I should had written $_POST['largo1'], $_POST['ancho1'] and $_POST['alto1'] :S I made That mistake only in transcription not in the original code, so I'm still having trouble getting form data but I'll take your advise and take a look on .serialized and .get methods.